# Database Relations Many To Many In ER model

Tags: database, database-design

How can we implement a Many To Many relation ship in an ER Model?

If this can't be done, why and what are the problems in implementing a Many To Many relationship?

Why are we converting many to many relationship into an one to many relation in an ER model?

Answer (score 2):

The ER model is not an implementation model.  It's an analysis model.  In the ER model, relationships are identified, but they are not implemented.

In the relational model, relationships are implemented by foreign key references.  By convention, FK references are always to the PK of a table, although, theoretically, they could be to any candidate key.

Many people draw ER diagrams with FKs stated on the diagram, as they are in a relational model. This makes a junction box needed for a many to many relationship, as it is in the relational model.  In pure ER, a many to many relationship just requires a line between two boxes, with both ends marked with the "many" indicator.

Pure ER is design agnostic.  ER as practiced by many people is biased towards a relational design.  There's nothing necessarily wrong with that, since most people intend to build a relational database.

Comment: thanks.. why theoretically they say you should convert a many to many association into a one to many association????

Comment: @Arun, because many people use ER diagramming as a substitute for relational diagramming. In a relational diagram, you need a box to represent the junction relation (or table). And you need the junction relation to hold the two foreign keys. In an ER diagram as such, you don't need to do this.